# Solving a QFT generator integral

Tags: integration

I have this integral
$$ Z=\int\!D\varphi(x^\mu)\, e^{ i\int d^4x\{\frac{1}{2}[(\partial\varphi)^2-m^2\varphi^2]+J\varphi \}  }. $$
It will suffice for my question to examine the integral with $\varphi(\vec x, t)\to\varphi(t)$ so that
$$ Z=\int\!D\varphi(t)\, e^{ i\int dt\{\frac{1}{2}[(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial t})^2-m^2\varphi^2]+J\varphi \}  }. $$
Integration by parts on the $\dot\varphi^2$ term yields
$$ Z=\int\!D\varphi(t)\, e^{ i\int dt[-\frac{1}{2}\varphi(\partial^2+m^2)\varphi+J\varphi ]  }. $$

The $\int D\varphi$ is such that for some irrelevant constant $\mathcal{C}$
$$  \int D\varphi(t) \equiv\mathcal{C}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(  \prod_n^\infty \int d\varphi_n\right) .$$
Therefore, letting $A=-(\partial^2+m^2)$, the integral of interest to me is
$$\frac{Z}{\mathcal{C}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(  \prod_n^\infty \int d\varphi_n\right) e^{ i\int dt[\frac{1}{2}\varphi A\varphi+J\varphi ]  },$$
which is where the first of my problems arise.  The $\varphi_n$ are supposed to be the $\varphi(t)$ at each of an infinite number of $t_n$ forming a continuum of $t$, and thus the infinite product.  This notation is a little hokey to me, so if you can make some suggestions here that would be helpful.  In the book I am using, Zee's QFT book, he uses a "trick" to solve the integral.  In general, I am asking this question on the math board because I do not want to use the trick and I want to solve the integral properly.  Zee suggests to imagine discretizing the integral in the exponent with
$$\frac{Z}{\mathcal{C}}=\left(  \prod_{n=1}^N \int d\varphi_n\right) e^{ \frac{i}{2}\varphi_i A_{ij}\varphi_j+J_k\varphi_k  },$$
where repeated indices are summed over.  Now we have a well known Gaussian integral that appears in many integral tables.  I am unsatisifed with the "imagine discretizing" procedure, even though I see how that makes sense for the discrete product of $\int d\varphi_n$.  What is the way to solve this integral without discretizing?  The answer to the integral is, with some new constant $\mathcal{C}'(N)$

$$\frac{Z}{\mathcal{C}'(N)}= e^{-\frac{i}{2}J_j\cdot A^{-1}_{jk}\cdot J_k},$$

which we "undiscretize" after the fact to obtain, setting $A^{-1}=D$

$$\frac{Z}{\mathcal{C}'(N)}=e^{-\frac{i}{2}\iint dt_1dt_2\, J(t_1)D(t_1-t_2)J(t_2) } .$$

How can I get here without "imagining discretizing?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "proper" way to construct or evaluate the path integrals of quantum field theory, and progress towards such has largely been limited to those of spacetime dimension 1 or 2; cf. the [Scholarpedia](http://scholarpedia.org/article/Path_integral:_mathematical_aspects) article. For the moment, arguing by analogy with genuine integrals is the best that can be done.

Comment: Nice link, thanks.  I will read it carefully.